# In an order $\mathcal{O}$, $I/mI\cong \mathcal{O}/m\mathcal{O}$ as $\mathcal{O}/m\mathcal{O}$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modules

Let $K$ be a quadratic field and $\mathcal{O}\subseteq K$ an order. I am trying to prove or construct a counterexample for the following statement:

*Let $I$ be an invertible ideal of $\mathcal{O}$. Then for every positive integer $m$, $I/mI\cong \mathcal{O}/m\mathcal{O}$ as $\mathcal{O}/m\mathcal{O}$-modules.*

Here an ideal $I$ of $\mathcal{O}$ is reversible if there is an ideal $J$ of $\mathcal{O}$ such $IJ = (\alpha) =\{\alpha r: r\in \mathcal{O}\}$.

My idea is this: I can prove that $|I/mI|=|\mathcal{O}/m\mathcal{O}|$. Now I'm trying to show that $ I / mI $ and $\mathcal{O}/m\mathcal{O}$ are $1$-generated. For example, this statement is true if $\mathcal{O}$ is a Dedekind domain, because $\mathcal{O}/I$ is a principal ideal domain for every ideal $I\neq 0$ of $\mathcal{O}$ in this case.

Could someone help me with any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to math.se. [Here are some guidelines on asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960). In particular, what have you tried? And what is your definition of invertible ideal? I may be missing something, but it seems like this should follow from the fact that $I I^{-1} = \mathcal{O}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Viktor Vaughn. I added the definition of an invertible ideal and my idea to prove the claim. If you can help me with any ideal, I will be very grateful.

Comment: You want to say that $I$ becomes principal $= bR$ in $R=O/\alpha m O$ so that $R/mR\cong bR/mbR=IR/mIR$

Comment: I need to prove now that $I/mI$ is a principal ideal of $\mathcal{O}/mI$. For example, this statement is true if $\mathcal{O}$ is a Dedekind domain, because $\mathcal{O}/mI$ is a  principal ideal domain in this case. Thanks for your comment @reuns.